# jQuery clone elements will not remain in div even when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

```
    function publicViewHandler(){
      //var pubView = new post();
      publish.set("publicView", true);
      publish.save();

      var publicQuery = new Parse.Query("Post");
      publicQuery.equalTo("publicView", true);
      publicQuery.equalTo("objectId", this.postId);

      // publicQuery.find({
      //   success:function(){
      //     // var myClone = $(this).parent().clone(true);
      //     // myClone.appendTo(".storyBoard");
      //     // myClone.append($(commentWindow).clone());
      //     }

          var myClone = $(this).parent().clone(true);
          myClone.appendTo(".storyBoard");
          myClone.append($(commentWindow).clone());

        //});
    }
```

My cloning works out side of the success function but it doesn't save to the element that it is appending to.  When the page is refreshed the clones disapear.

Checkout my url at http://www.subdomain.jason-c.com.  Both login and password is kio..  If you make a new story, save it then publish it, the clone will be appended but then refresh and they disapear.

Also, how would I work that code in to my query because the way I did it does not seem to be even apending the clones of the selected stories.

Comment: You're just modifying the local DOM, you're not changing the web page on the server.

Comment: You need to send changes to a database on the server.

Comment: So would I do it the same way as I queried for the saved stories ?

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript/jQuery is a client side manipulation.**

You're making changes on the client side (browser) and not on the server side (your website), that's why the changes disappear on refresh.

To make it not disappear on refresh, you need to make it server side. Add the code on your HTML or use an ajax request and tell the server what code should be included on the HTML code.

Comment: It's not out of the question to keep it all client-side with local storage etc. but for the sake of an easier answer, I guess describing the issue in these terms is best!